# why is this code not removing duplicates from the list?

Tags: python, list, module

I am learning python from Youtube and want to write a python code which removes duplicates from the list. This is my code :

```
nums = [1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,8,5,6,6,4,4,7,5,8]
j = 1
for i in nums :
    if nums.count(i) > 1 :
        while j < nums.count(i) :
            nums.remove(i)
            j += 1
print(nums)
```

I know there are other ways to do it but i want to know why this one isn't working. are the all the modules correct?

Comment: Don't remove items from a list while you're iterating over it.  Bad things happen.

Answer (score 0):

You are not resetting your counter (`j`) each time and it continues to increment. Try moving the `j = 1` into the `for` loop.

But you shouldn't ever mutate a list as you iterate through it.